# Connecting to a linked server in R

Tags: r, linked-server

`select * from openquery ( oracle, 'select * from tablename1')` --- this works in    sql server

I used the `RODBC` package

```
fd1 <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * 
             FROM t1') -- This works
fd2 <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * 
            FROM openquery (Oracle, "select * from tablname1 where id is null")')
```

---  This works. But when I call the object `fd2`, I get the following -

> [1] "42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'select * from tablename1 where id is null'."
>
> [2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select * from openquery (oracle, \"select * from tablename1 where id is null\")'"

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

fd2 is using double quotes around the embedded SQL query.  T-SQL requires single quotes.  Do this instead:

```
fd2 <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 
    'select * FROM openquery (Oracle, \'select * from tablname1 where id is null\')')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!